# Android Contact Picker [multiple hp number and how to display in EditText]

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to create 3 TextView field and every each of TextView field display the selected contact number. 
I succeed with 1 TextView only but I have no idea to deal with multiple contacts.

```
contactNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
Button buttonPickContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickcontact);
buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }});
```

below shows how I display the hp number just for 1 contact, but how to display multiple phone number ? For example, TextView1 display 123, TextView2 display 456 and so on.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RQS_PICK_CONTACT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String number =       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            //contactName.setText(name);
            contactNumber.setText(number);
            //contactEmail.setText(email);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want 3 `TextView`s with 3 `Button`s (next to each `TextView`), or you want a single `Button` for all 3 `TextView`s?

Comment: 3 TextViews with 3 Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply run your code three times, and on each one use a different `TextView` id, `Button` id, and `RequestCode`.

You can use a helper method, like this:

```
private void setupViews(long textViewId, long buttonId, final int requestCode) {
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(buttonId);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        }
   });
}
```

Call it 3 times, for each `TextView`-`Button` pair:

```
setupViews(R.id.my_first_text_view, R.id.my_first_button, 1000);
setupViews(R.id.my_second_text_view, R.id.my_second_button, 2000);
setupViews(R.id.my_third_text_view, R.id.my_third_button, 3000);
```

Then handle the `ActivityResult` per the `requestCode` (move your existing update code to a method called `updateTextView`):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            updateTextView(R.id.my_first_text_view);
        } else if (requestCode == 2000) {
            updateTextView(R.id.my_second_text_view);
        } else if (requestCode == 3000) {
            updateTextView(R.id.my_third_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```